# First time install 13.04

Tags: android, eclipse, 13.04

I have been wanting to make the switch from Windows to Ubuntu for a while now and decided to do a test run by dual booting on my tower. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 as it was the latest version and had no issues with the set-up. Now that I have it installed I am having issues figuring things out.

A main thing that is bugging me is I tried to set up eclipse using the ADT package(http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). When it runs if I minimize the window disappears and the icon is not on the sidebar.

Another thing is there seems to be a problem with the Software Centre. When I go to see the currently installed applications, it shows a white screen with an unanimated loading circle in the middle and the cursor turns to the loading cursor.

I guess my question would be is should I downgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 and do my set-up there or just wait for the next update.

Also taking your recommendations if you think I should choose another Linux distribution for Android development.

Comment: 13.04 is still in development and will be unstable, so yes 12.10 or 12.04 LTS would be more functional.

Comment: Hm. I never installed Eclipse but... Sorry for the silly question. Is it possible to install Eclipse from a terminal? Certainly you will get some error messages there

Comment: I dont think the issue is with Eclipse. I think it is a bug with 13.04. Chris I think I will downgrade and start again. If you want, make that an answer and I’ll accept it.

Comment: Related Question -> [theres an issue with an alpha-beta](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do/18651#18651)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your question relates to an alpha or beta release of Ubuntu. Such questions are generally not within Ask Ubuntu's ambit. Please look at [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/25656) for further assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

13.04 is still in development and will be unstable with some packages not yet supported so yes 12.10 or 12.04 LTS would be more functional.