# rMBP 10,1 Bluetooth not working

Tags: bluetooth, macbook-pro, 13.04

I got my 13" macbook pro retina laptop pretty much all working on Ubuntu apart from bluetooth.

I can pair a device no problem. I pair it as a Headset Service. But I cannot see any audio device in the bluetooth settings.

if i do

```
pactl list cards short
0 alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 module-alsa-card.c
```

Is shown, and nothing else..

So I have it paired,  how do I get a output device to show?

Comment: Hi - 13.04 issues should be reported on launchpad to allow the developers to actually fix this issue.  Please refer to this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: I know, It was not a bug, I did not have the packaged installed otherwise I would have reported it as a bug. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

I installed bluez and installed pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (this showed up my headset). I then was able to get it working, and selected the A2DP profile. Now all works.