# Remove lvm to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, gparted, lvm

I am trying to install Ubuntu. However I have an lvm on the drive I want to install Ubuntu on.

Gparted cannot remove the lvm which is /dev/sda6.

How can I remove the lvm to instal lvm over it?

Comment: Why you added the 13.04 tag? This is an non supported Ubuntu version!

Comment: +Lucio.  Raring ringtail not supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: You don't know it yet? Questions about an [alpha/beta Ubuntu version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) (under development) are off-topic.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is **my fault**, I expressed myself badly. I was referring that **we** (Ask Ubuntu) don't create content about those versions. Because there are under development. Once again, sorry for the misunderstanding..

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have data on the drive that you need to keep, back it up.

2) Fill the drive with zeros which will blow away the MBR, Partition table LVM and all data by:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`

or if you want a progress report as you wipe the drive use

`sudo dc3dd wipe=/dev/sdX` in both cases sdX should be changed to sda, sdb, or whatever drive you are wiping. You can identify the drives using

`fdisk -l`