# Mounting a second hard drive for documents, pictures, and music in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, hard-drive

I wanted to know how to make my secondary drive for documents, music, and pictures. I already formatted the drive and mounted the drive in /media/bigdata. Now I just want to know on how to make all my file go to that drive or at least have access to it, so I can put in files. Thanks.

** This is what I get when I try to move a file to the new mounted hardrive. This is what I get when I try to move a file to it. Error opening file '/media/bigdata/uninstalling wine.odt'. Permission denied.

How do I use chown to change my permissions in my new drive, so I can copy and paste on it?

Here is my original post of the process. [How to add a second hard drive to an already installed Xubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488213/how-to-add-a-second-hard-drive-to-an-already-installed-xubuntu-14-04/490884#490884)

*** When I go to the new partition drive and I open the terminal in that location and I type Ls -L this is what I get total 16
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Jul  3 10:05 lost+found

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670

Answer (score 0):

Just copy them ?

```
cp -r ~/{Pictures,Videos,Music} /media/bigdata
```

Or maybe move them ?

```
mv ~/{Pictures,Videos,Music} /media/bigdata
```

Just adapt these commands. **What you write in `/media/bigdata` is written to the external drive mounted there.** However, if you want to use this drive as your `/home` partition, that's another thing. Quoting from [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/) :

> If you don’t create a separate home partition while installing Ubuntu, you don’t have to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. To migrate to a separate home partition after installation, you’ll have to create a new partition (which may require resizing your existing partitions), copy the files from your existing home directory to that partition, and tell Ubuntu to mount the new partition at /home.

As you're using the whole drive, you probably don't need to partition it much more. Copying/moving is handled by my above commands. As far as auto-mounting is concerned, you might want to have a look at the [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) file. GNOME also offers device auto-mounting GUIs that mount your drive to `/media/bigdata` after login. Basically, most USB storage devices are auto-mounted anyway.

In you're not really at ease with disk management and system partitionning, just move your files to the drive, and leave your `/home` partition where it is. You might just need to configure your system to mount the external drive at `/media/bigdata`.

Comment: Also, in order to serve as the /home partition, the file system should be formatted as ext4.

Comment: @Jos Even though it's becoming a standard, ext4 is not the only possibility. Linux can mount numerous filesystems, no matter if it's `/home` or another partition.

Comment: True. But you need a permissions system like ext4 offers, or your home partition will become a mess.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith this is my original problem which I solved, but now I can't even copy or paste to the new drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/488213/how-to-add-a-second-hard-drive-to-an-already-installed-xubuntu-14-04?noredirect=1#comment655882_488213

Comment: @jart Then maybe you should provide us with more information about the new error. Edit your question and tell user "why" you can't copy :)

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I mounted the drive and everything I just can't copy and paste on it. Is like I need a permission or something. Like modifying it with chown, but how. This is what I get when I try to move a file to it. Error opening file '/media/bigdata/uninstalling wine.odt'. Permission denied.

How do I use chown to change my permissions in my new drive, so I can copy and paste on it?

Comment: You just *use* it : `sudo chown -R you:yourgroup /media/bigdata`