# Cannot delete LVM (to install Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I would like to install Ubuntu 20.04 from scratch. I booted on a live USB, but the install failed as my previous lvm partition /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg could not be removed. Using gparted (after deactivating the partition), it fails on the command:

```
lvm pvremove --force --force --yes '/dev/sda3'
WARNING: PV /dev/sda3 in VG ubuntu-mate-vg is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
WARNING: PV /dev/sda3 is used by VG ubuntu-mate-vg.
WARNING: Wiping physical volume label from /dev/sda3 of volume group "ubuntu-mate-vg".
Error writing device /dev/sda3 at 512 length 512.
bcache_invalidate: block (5, 0) still dirty
Failed to remove label from /dev/sda3 at sector 1
Failed to wipe existing label(s) on /dev/sda3.
```

Following [Remove lvm to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267968/remove-lvm-to-install-ubuntu) I tried to fill the drive with zeros with:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda3 bs=8M
```

(which eventually failed with "out of space").
I still get the issue above.
Any idea?
Thanks a lot!