# Will windows 8 work after i install Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, menu

I had searched and found many GRUB related problem after installing windows 8 over ubuntu or ubuntu over windows 8.So i fear to install ubuntu 12.04.

So What is the measures i need to take while installing Ubuntu so that after restart both windows 8 & ubuntu will show up in boot menu and even after updating UBUNTU.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For the question related to installing Ubuntu on a computer with Windows 8 see the answer in [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) that should cover everything related to installing Ubuntu on a computer with Windows 8. Note that if you do not suffer from the UEFI issue, you only need to install Ubuntu. The grub will simply work and grab the Windows 8 partition. Tested on way too many computers / laptops.

If you however, did it backwards, with this I mean, you have Ubuntu and installed Windows afterwards. Then you need to follow the answers found in [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

In any case, since 13.04 came out, I recommend using 13.04 over 12.04. You will have better support for issues like this, more hardware support, more fixes, optimizations and more. For a brief explanation of why I would suggest to go with the 13.04 release please read [install 13.04 or stay with 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284239/install-13-04-or-stay-with-12-04-lts/284245#284245)

Answer (score 0):

Installing any dual-boot operating system setup should not be done without having a good backup and recovery strategy. Most OEM computers come with full restore capabilities and you can create repair discs beforehand. Data can be backed up. While in most cases, this is unnecessary, it pays to be careful.

Unfortunately there are some issues with UEFI and dual booting which can be seen in the [[Boot-Repair] Graphical tool to repair the PC boot in 1 click!](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769482) thread on ubuntuforums.org (it's long so look from the back). These are not necessarily Ubuntu related - it seems different manufacturers have implemented UEFI differently and not with dual booting in mind.

Over time this process should become smoother.