# Can I choose the position of a partition while installing Ubuntu as a dual boot with Windows?

Tags: installation, partitioning

When installing Ubuntu, is there a way you can choose which part of the disk you want your partition to be on? I am partitioning a 2TB HDD, giving 300GB to Ubuntu, however I don't want this partition in the middle of the HDD, as it is used as my storage drive for Windows.

Comment: What have you tried? And remember that 13.04 is not yet released and therefore off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: @gertvdijk Sorry - First post on this site! I haven't yet tried it, I was Googleing to try to find an answer but couldn't find anything, so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Don't know about 13.04, but if all else fails, I guess you can partition your HD using GParted, leave a non-partitioned space where you want 13.04 to be, and then use the free space option on the installer. Unless something is really different with 13.04.

Comment: Fortunately there are many other help resources you can use for help with Ubuntu+1 problems, in case you experience others. See [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do). However, since this already has a valuable, upvoted, accepted answer that applies to stable, currently supported releases and is *in no way specific to 13.04*, we should probably not close this question.

Comment: @EliahKagan, please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running the ubuntu installer, you are given two options:

- Use entire harddisk
- Manually configure partition table

Select the second option and layout the disk as you like. This works best if the disk is empty. Otherwise you could destroy existing files/partitions if it's not done correctly.

eg first partition 'ext4'(300gb), second partition 'linux swap'(4-12gb), third partition 'ntfs'(rest)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't entirely sure if I would get this option. My disk is completely defragmented, so hopefully it should all be grouped together, and I won't erase anything. I didn't want large head movements when in Windows if there was a large partition in the middle, that was my reason for asking. Thanks!

Comment: Remember if you _move_ partitions all content will become erased/unusuable. To avoid that modify partitions without data only. All with data have to remain untouched/stay in the same place on disk.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear that in mind. Hopefully I won't need to move any partitions, and I have everything backed up anyway.