# Flickering only on VGA output on Lenovo T400 (ATI Radeon HD3400)

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

Just now installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 and upgrade to latest GNOME 3.8 version. On GNOME Classic when I'm opening applications it's FLICKERING on VGA 1920x1080.

Display settings:

```
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV620 [Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:cfff0000-cfffffff memory:cff00000-cff1ffff
```

Kernel:

```
xx@xx:~$ uname -a
Linux xx 3.8.0-16-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 1 19:55:09 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Currently is using open source AMD ATI Radeon driver, i'm not using propriatery driver from AMD site. Using 3400HD AMD Radeon.

Latest driver from AMD is AMD Catalyst™ 13.1 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver released 1/21/2013, and I'm not sure can I install it for sure or waiting final release. Found `Kernel version up to 3.4` for proprietary driver.

Flickering appears only on FULL HD resolution (1920x1080) not on 1680x1050.

Now, how can I resolve flickering on VGA with open source driver?

Comment: Your question relates to a beta release of Ubuntu. According to the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq), Ask Ubuntu is probably not the right place for such questions. The FAQ has links to help you better understand what is welcome and where. Also, Ubuntu Forums has a [subforum dedicated to alpha and beta releases](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427)

Comment: See also [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) and [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check your cables.

But if it is the graphics driver that is the problem, then you may have no choice but to attempt to use the AMD proprietary driver with the 3.8 kernel, and if it doesn't work, wait until AMD comes out with a new release that works with the this kernel.

Besides the proprietary driver, there is always the xorg-edgers ppa, which you can check out [here](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa). If you add it to your system, you will get very new releases of xorg software. Some bug fixes required to fix your particular issue may be included in those packages.

Comment: fixed, reverting back to intel graphic card. thank you. I will wait for released new driver for ATI driver.