# libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object and skype doesn't start

Tags: 64-bit, skype, 13.04

```
$ uname -a
Linux homebook 3.8.0-17-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Sun Apr 7 19:39:35 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo find / -name libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1


$ skype
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It wasn't helpful for me.

Comment: If that does not work you will be out of luck: it will be considered a bug in a beta release so this needs to be reported on the bugtracker ;) ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do )

Comment: good!! if you want create an answer with what exactly worked for you if it was not covered in the link I posted and you can accept it yourself.