# Xubuntu xfce context menu weird display

Tags: xubuntu, 13.10, xfce4

I tried to install 'gnome-shell' through synaptic manager but I didn't like it so got it uninstalled...however even after running 'autoremove' & 'autoclean' commands a problem persists & that is related to the context menu of **both** nemo & nautilus file browsers (I got them installed instead of thunar). The problem is shown below
[image]

However these weird lines **don't occur** in the context menu of builtin thunar file browser...but I never use it!

This problem also occurs in the context menu of synaptic packet manager
[image]

Also in the context menu at xfce desktop these weird lines too are absent
[image]

Comment: As per the FAQ - questions about alpha/beta issues are off-topic.  Please see this Q for details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 2):

You have a mix of GTK+ 2 and 3 applications; these use different theme engines. Install `ubuntu-tweak` to reset the GTK3 theme to its GTK2 counterpart. (xfce4 is still GTK2 and hence agnostic of GTK3)

If `ubuntu tweak` is too heavy, you can also manually edit `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`
Mine looks as follows:

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name = elementary
gtk-icon-theme-name = elementary-xfce
gtk-fallback-icon-theme = gnome
gtk-sound-theme-name = ubuntu
gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu-bar=24,24
gtk-font-name = Droid Sans 9
```

Also, if you don't want to change the default gtk3 theme for all users, edit:

`~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

Comment: I can't install ubuntu-tweak in xubuntu its too big for this bug, can u suggest an alternative

Comment: I have edited my post.