# apache2-prefork-dev missing in saucy?

Tags: package-management, apache2, launchpad, 13.10

I am trying to build my package (which works fine on precise, quantal, raring) in launchpad, but on saucy I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-prefork-dev : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-6ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
```

Is this package deprecated? Or is there just some trouble in the saucy development pool?

Comment: This question risks being closed as **off topic** as its about a development release. If you believe you have found a bug see [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/107450) or for more general questions you may want to ask in [Ubuntu Forums: Ubuntu+1](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427)

Comment: It looks like the problem here is that apache2-prefork-dev is now a virtual package provided by apache2-dev in saucy, but for some reason the old apache2-prefork-dev deb for 2.2.22-6ubuntu5 never got deleted (I still see it in the Packages file), so it tries to install that instead. Might be worth raising a bug about it. Though it seems like you might want to move to deping on apache2-dev instead, since that seems to be all that is left.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well.

It seems like `apache2-dev-2.4.4-6ubuntu5` (the new version just uploaded today) now conflicts with and provides `apache2-prefork-dev`. See [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/apache2-dev/2.4.4-6ubuntu5).

Comment: Hmm this worries me. Are they getting rid of prefork?

Comment: Also: what would be a way to specify my control file such that it will work in both precise and saucy. Can I just do: `Depends: apache2-prefork-dev | apache2-dev` ?

Comment: Is it only the `-dev` package that changes? It seems like `apache2-mpm-prefork` will still be the same in saucy?

Comment: I think you could do: `Depends: apache2-prefork-dev | apache2-dev (>= 2.4.4-6ubuntu5)` but I'm not 100% certain on that.  I haven't looked at the changes in detail but they probably merged the -dev packages together somehow.