# Upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10: Computer won't boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, upgrade, 13.10

I upgraded from 12.04 to 13.10 and my computer boots to a black screen.  I hear the drumroll, but there is no functionality after that.

I've downloaded a livecd of 12.04 on my other computer, and I changed the BiOS settings to boot from CD/DVD first, but it still does the same thing.

I booted advanced options, edited [ro quick splash] to [ro nomodeset] and it started normally.  I rebooted the system and it was back to the same junk.  What do I need to do while it is operating to make it reliable with every restart?

This seems to be a systemic issues with NUMEROUS Ubuntu upgrades, but I haven't read a solution yet.  I need some help, please!  Thanks.

Comment: There is no upgrade path from 12.04 to 13.10 aside the fact that 13.10 still is not released. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 0):

This is because the kernel is attempting to load video drivers before X server starts. 'nomodeset' allows your video card to use the BIOS display until X starts. To make nomodeset a permanent boot option follow this guide:

[Nomodeset](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)