# Upgrading to Alpha fails due extras repositories

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I try to upgrade to the latest release of Ubuntu (14.04  - Alpha).

I typed this in the Terminal:

```
$ sudo update-manager -d
```

After some checks, a popup appeared:

[image]

I clicked the <kbd>Upgrade...</kbd> button:

[image]

*Preparing to upgrade* was successful, but *Setting new sofware channels* fails:

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: This is not uncommon on alpha releases. 14.04 is very much still in development and not ready for anybody other than the developers.  This question is off topic here see [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/107450).

Comment: @WarrenHill Is this really a bug or I have some settings that must be fixed on my machine?

Comment: **This is not a bug but a feature!** The [*`extras` entries from `/etc/apt/sources.list`*](http://askubuntu.com/a/379443/148451) must be removed to be able to upgrade. So, I believe that the close votes can be removed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just disable the "extra" repositories. These packages still not have trusty counter part, since most of them are for Stable versions:

[image]

To disable the extras repositories, just remove all the `extras` entries from `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or use the software sources and untick the extras entries there.

```
sudo sed -i '/extras\.ubuntu\.com/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```