# Low Graphics mode after 15.04 ISO

Tags: system-installation, intel, ivybridge

Booted 15.04 desktop ISO and went no where. "The system is running in low-graphics mode" screen popped up with "Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

I restarted held shift down n was unable to enter recovery mode/screen. I am able to get into a terminal w a network connection though.
 This is on a 14.04 Ubuntu system w a Intel graphics card, ivy bridge, 16gb ram, and a Intel ssd. Please help. *Update* I ran Ubuntu installation disc so now I have a virtual environment to work with on the computer too.

Comment: Note: 15.04 has not been released. This question is referring to an unreleased development version.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by.

```
    kiri@xxx-cpu:~$ sudo apt-get update
    kiri@xxx-cpu:~$ sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
    kiri@xxx-cpu:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
    kiri@xxx-cpu:~$ sudo apt-get install gdm
    clicked on install lightgdm
    kiri@xxx-cpu:~$ sudo reboot
```