# system running low graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, ssd

I've just installed Ubuntu on a fresh machine had Nothing on it just a 120gb SSD, 1TB HDD.

Once it finished installing which was pretty fast on the SSD, 
I restarted my PC only to get the error  *`System running low graphics`* I, of course, googled it and turns out that some AMD GPU's are having compatibility issues with Ubuntu. the fix apparently is to go to recovery mode and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get into Terminal command.

The only problem is that it's asking me to log in... sure I try to log in but when it asks for my password it wont let me type Anything.. and just keeps going.

I have no idea how to fix this... any tips? video links maybe ?

Comment: when it asking for password you wont see anything because it will not be printed on the screen, just key in your password and enter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix "Your system is running in low-graphics mode"?](http://askubuntuhttp://askubuntu.com/questions/569395/low-graphics-mode-after-15-04-iso.com/questions/125453/how-do-i-fix-your-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal behaviour.

When entering a password into a Linux text-user-interface, no characters are visible, despite the fact that your *are* actually entering your password.

So; enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - you should now login successfully.

Comment: still i cant login even after trying that it just wont let me get into my desktop even on the "try before installing"