# Where can I download Quantal 12.10 Alpha 2?

Tags: downloads, iso, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get the latest Ubuntu Alpha or Beta?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12516/where-can-i-get-the-latest-ubuntu-alpha-or-beta)

I can not download the image through the link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/TechnicalOverview/Alpha2
the error  is "The requested URL /releases/quantal/alpha-2/ was not found on this server."

Comment: Yeah i have verified it and facing the same issue .

Answer (score 1):

Alpha-2 version of Quantal will be releases TODAY (28 June 2012). It's not downloadable yet, but it should be in the next hours at the specified addresses. Probably the wiki has been updated before the ISOs are really added to ftp.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative download image  from

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/